# Does the limit of c exist or not

Tags: mathematical-statistics, entropy, nonparametric-density

Let say m is dimension
$\exists$ $f(x)$ $f$ is density function
and

\begin{equation*}
    f(x) = \frac{c(m,a,b)}{\|x\|^a\left(\log\frac{e}{\|x\|}\right)^{b}}\mathbf{1}_{\|x\|\leq 1} \geq 0
\end{equation*}
where $a$ and $b$ depend on $m$ dimension and also we know the density function is 
\begin{equation*}
    \int_{\mathbb{R}^m}f(x)dx = 1.
\end{equation*}
Let 
\begin{equation*}
    c_0 = \frac{1}{\int_{\|x\|\leq 1}\|x\|^a\left(\log\frac{e}{\|x\|}\right)^{b}dx}
\end{equation*}
Suppose that $\rho = \|x\| $, then we have
\begin{equation*}
   c= \frac{2\pi^{m/2}}{\Gamma(m/2)}\int_0^1\rho^{m-1}\rho^{-a}\left(\log\frac{e}{\rho}\right)^{-b}\,d\rho.
\end{equation*}
So, my question is how do we know limit of $c$ exist or not.
Thanks a lot in advance

Note: $\mathbf{1}$ is indicator

Comment: What variable(s) are you changing in taking this limit??  And are you asking about $c$ or $1/c$ (which you seem to interchange)?

Comment: @whuber this looks like the OP is expressing a density function of the form

$$ f(x) \propto \frac{1}{\|x\|^a\left(\log\frac{e}{\|x\|}\right)^{b}}\mathbf{1}_{\|x\|\leq 1}$$

and wishes to compute some normalization coefficient but does not know whether the integral is finite. 

It is similar as this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427352/how-to-know-this-integral-finite-or-infinite/427356

Comment: @Martijn The connection with the previous question is clear, but the references to "limit" mean something important has not yet been explained.

Comment: With the answers from that related question (substituting $u = 1 - log(x)$) the integral expression becomes: 

$$  \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^a\left(\log\frac{e}{x}\right)^{b}} dx = e^{1-a} \int_1^\infty e^{(a-1)u} u^{-b} du$$ and it is a matter of where, for which $a$ and $b$, the integral converges.

Comment: @whuber I edited the draft, i want to see the integral of c exists or not exists. As to limit. maybe we can consider for  which $a$ and $b$, the integral converges where $a$ and $b$ depend on $m$ dimension

Comment: The same analyses used to answer your previous question will answer this one, too.